# How to add derived properties to a Jackson 2 serialized class?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm serializing some existing objects with Jackson 2.22, leveragin the MixIn feature to decouple the real object from the Jackson annotations configuration.

Actually my mixin is an interface that declares the same methods of the target class and annotates them, here's an example.

Target class:

```java
public class Product {

    // ...

    public String getName();

    public String getDescription();

    public String getPrice();

    public String getFinalPrice();

    public String getDiscount();

    // ...

}
```

and the mixin:

```java
public interface ProductApi {

    @JsonProperty
    public String getName();

    @JsonProperty("price")
    public String getFinalPrice();

}
```

My JSON should have some more informations, computed from several methods or fields of the target class.

Is this even possible in Jackson?

I tried turning the mixin in a class and adding a new method there, but that didn't work.

```java
public class ProductApi {

    @JsonProperty
    public String getName();

    @JsonProperty("price")
    public String getFinalPrice();

    @JsonProperty("images")
    public List<String> getImages() { /* ... */ }

}
```

I guess this is because the mixin only provides annotations for the target class, but is the latter that is read for serialization.

Of course, if I change the object to be serialized with a new subclass that contains the new method I need, that works, but the objects come from our services layers, and this would mean I have to rewrite all those methods.

I'm using Jackson with Jersey, so don't want to change Jackson with another library.

Comment: so if I understand, you pass an instance of `Product ` to ObjectMapper and because `Product` implements `ProductApi`, then ObjectMapper reads the annotations from there

Comment: @sharonbn The whole story is that `Product` is returned inside a custom object encapsulated in a JAX-RS [Response object](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html), whose serialization is mediated by a custom `ObjectMapper` provided by a [ContextResolver](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/index.html?javax/ws/rs/core/Configurable.html) that configures it with the mixin, but yes, that's what ultimately happens :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it.

The solution is to specify a custom [JsonSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) implementation to the field getter.

First of all, I changed the mixin `interface` to a `class` that extends the entity (target) class, so that it can access the target class data.

```java
public class ProductApi extends Product {

    @JsonProperty
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    };

    // ...

}
```

Next, I implemented the `JsonSerializer` that would create the derived property I want:

```java
public static class ImagesSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Product p = (Product) jgen.getCurrentValue();

        int num = p.getNumberOfImages();

        List<String> imgs = new ArrayList<String>(num);

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            String src = "/include/images/showImage.jsp?"+"id="+p.getId()+"&number="+i;
            imgs.add(src);
        }

        provider.defaultSerializeValue(imgs, jgen);
    }

}
```

*This is a really simple implementation, more safety checks should be done.*

What this does is, basically, retrieve the whole entity instance from the JSON generator, build up a custom object and then ask Jackson to serialize it.
I implemented it inside my `ProductApi` as a static class, but just for simplicity.

Finally, the serializer needs to be bound to the `JsonProperty` annotated field:

```java
public class ProductApi extends Product {

    @JsonProperty
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    };

    // ...

    @JsonSerialize(using=ImagesSerializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("images")
    @Override
    public String getImage() { // in my entity this returns an image number, whereas in my JSON I want a list of URLs
        return "";
    }

    // ...

}
```

As a side note, it seems that the returned value of the `getImage()` method is not used.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just make some fields, which should be serialized and use Gson for it?

Comment: Uh, I forgot to add that I'm using Jackson with Jersey, so I want to stick with this library. Going to edit my question.

Comment: "making some fields" and serializing them is also achievable in Jackson. actually, Jackson is superior to gson feature-wise