# how to get property or field name in a custom json serializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a [custom JsonSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) for a field (simplified code):

```java
@JsonSerialize(using=Text1Serializer.class)
@JsonProperty("text1") // I need this inside the custom serializer
@Override
public String getTextOne() {
    return "foo";
}

// ...

public static class Text1Serializerextends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // how to get "text1" here?
        provider.defaultSerializeValue(value, jgen);
    }

}
```

Since I need to serialize about ten other fields with a similar logic, that just depends on the field *name*, it would help me very much if I could get the property name inside the custom serializer - instead of writing ten identical serializers.

I've seen that inside the `serialize()` method I can get the whole object with `JsonGenerator.getCurrentValue()` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33414406/3127111)), but I didnt' find a way to get the field name.

I'm using Jackson 2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement ContextualSerializer, this will be used to produce a "contextual" version of your serializer, i.e. one that is configured using the BeanProperty:

```
public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property)
    throws JsonMappingException;
```

This should return a new instance that is customised for the given property: it doesn't have to be the same class as the non-customised serializer (although the standard Jackson implementations all seem to work that way).

Comment: Are you talking about adding a private field in my `JsonSerializer`, field that `createContextual()` sets with `property.getName()` and finally returns `this`? If so, it looks a bit ugly, but works.

Comment: @watery: createContextual() should create a new instance of your serializer with the property name added, not just modify itself

Answer (score 4):

You can get field name in a custom json serializer like this:

```
@JsonComponent
public class Text1Serializerextends extends JsonSerializer<String> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        // will output "text1"
        System.out.println(jgen.getOutputContext().getCurrentName());

        provider.defaultSerializeValue(value, jgen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current property name by calling **jgen.getOutputContext().getCurrentName()**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through Customized SerzializerProvider

```
public class EmptyContentSerializerProvider extends DefaultSerializerProvider {

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<Object> findNullValueSerializer(BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
         property.getName(); //this can extract the filed name
    }
}
```