# Jackson deserialize string value that contains valid json

Tags: java, json, jackson

Suppose I have the following JSON data:

```
{
    "header": "some value",
    "message": "{\"field1\": \"abc\", \"field2\": 123}"
}
```

Is it possible to adjust the annotations on OuterClass so the `message` field will be parsed as an InnerClass object?

```
public class InnerClass {
    @JsonProperty("field1")
    public void setField1(String value) {/* do stuff */}

    @JsonProperty("field2")
    public void setField2(Integer value) {/* do stuff */}
}

public class OuterClass {
    @JsonProperty("message")
    public void setMessage(InnerClass obj) {/* do stuff */}  
}
```

Ideally I would like the calling code to look something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
OuterClass obj = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, OuterClass.class);
```

Comment: I guess so, Jackson is pretty flexible. But I don't have the code I've worked on here, see if you can find anything useful in these two questions of mine: [first](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33408640/3127111) and [second](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33519354/3127111)

Comment: I'll look into them.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure your outer class to have a property of the other class that represents the nested JSON, like:

```
public class OuterClass {

    @JsonProperty("header")
    private String header; 

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private InnerClass message; 

    //getters & setters
}
```

Comment: I managed to get this approach to work.  However, I had to create a constructor that accepts the values.  It would not use the default constructor and then call the setters.  Error: `Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, InnerClass] from JSON String; 
no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: InnerClass)`

Answer (score 1):

Once I added some complexity, the accepted answer would not work.  I kept getting the error:

`Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, InnerClass] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: InnerClass)`

I ended up using the following approach

```
public class OuterClass {
    public InnerClass message;

    @JsonCreator
    public OuterClass (Map<String,Object> delegate) throws IOException {
        String json = (String)delegate.get("Message");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.message = mapper.readValue(json, InnerClass.class);
     }
}
```